# How to upload my iMovie project to iCloud drive?

Tags: icloud, imovie

I would like to get my iMovie project on my iPad. My iCloud Drive is turned on on every device. I mean the **project**, not the result from the theater. Video from theater is there on my device. But what about project? In my iMovie preferences my checkbox `Automatically upload...` is checked...

Answer (score 2):

Find the project file, then copy it and paste it into iCloud Drive in finder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Project file? What extension has a project file? Is not a directory with subdirectories?

Comment: It is a directory with subdirectories, your mac will allow it to be executed on iOS.